# Why do Dictionaries return an optional, but Arrays do not?

Tags: swift

For an Array, if you try to access an index outside of the array's existing bounds, it will trigger a runtime error. However, if you try to access a Dictionary key that does not exist, you will get an 'nil' (optional). Why can't the Array do the same thing?

I am trying to understand why Dictionaries return optionals and Arrays don't?

Comment: My gut tells me the API designers considered the likely use cases and decided that most array access will be on a index known to be in range or a simple check can be made in the less common cases where you aren't sure. But a dictionary it's quite common to not be sure if a key exists so it made more sense to return nil than throw an exception.

Comment: Despite the "opinion based" close votes, Rob Mayoff's excellent answer shows that this question can be answered objectively and with references to sources that explain the actual reasoning behind the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find an official answer in [the “Commonly Rejected Proposals” document](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/commonly_proposed.md#strings-characters-and-collection-types) that is part of the official Swift Evolution repository:

> - Change `Array<T>` subscript access to return `T?` or `T!` instead of `T`: The current array behavior is [intentional](https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-add-safe-subquence-access-via-subscript-for-colloctiontype/516/7), as it accurately reflects the fact that out-of-bounds array access is a logic error. Changing the current behavior would slow `Array` accesses to an unacceptable degree. Changing the unlabeled array subscript to return an optional has come up [multiple](https://forums.swift.org/t/proposal-add-safe-subquence-access-via-subscript-for-colloctiontype/516/5) times before and is very unlikely to be accepted.

The “intentional” link leads to a December 2015 Swift mailing list post (converted to a Swift Forums post) by Dave Abrahams, one of the lead implementors of the older parts of the Swift standard library:

> Thank you, Brent; that captures the rationale exactly. The one thing missing is the performance piece: allowing arrays to do anything other than abort on out-of-range accesses would make them non-competitive with C arrays.

Here Dave is endorsing a post by Becca (formerly Brent) Royal-Gordon, which says:

> The use cases for arrays and dictionaries are different, though.
>
> I’d say about 80% of the time you subscript an array, you’re using an index that was somehow derived *from* the array—for instance, a range like `0..<array.count`, or `array.indices`, or `array[indexPath.row]` where `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` returns `array.count`. This is very different from dictionaries, where the key is usually some piece of data from somewhere *else* and you’re trying to look up the value corresponding to it. You rarely say, for instance, `array[2]` or `array[someRandomNumberFromSomewhere]`, but `dictionary[“myKey”]` or `dictionary[someRandomValueFromSomewhere]` are pretty common.
>
> Because the use cases are different, arrays have a non-optional subscriptor which fails a precondition when the index is invalid, while dictionaries have an optional subscriptor which returns nil when the index is invalid.